# Bundle SQL scripts for Oracle

Tags: oracle, scripting

I have bunch of sql-scripts used to create various tables, procedures, functions and views. Everything is in separate files; is there a good way to bundle these and run each file in a specific order? Merging/concatenating all the files into one is also a possibility, but I'd prefer a bundle if possible.

Example (fictional/pseudocode): Master.sql contains the following:

```
src: DDL/table1.sql
src: DDL/table2.sql
src: fns/function1.sql
src: fns/function2.sql
src: views/view1.sql
```

...and so on. Running Master.sql would then execute each of the scripts listed in the file in the order listed. Is something like this possible?

Comment: The answer obviously depends on what client you use to run your scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend the scripts with an `@` in your `master.sql` script:

```
@DDL/table1.sql
@DDL/table2.sql
@fns/function1.sql
@fns/function2.sql
@views/view1.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run them in SQLPlus like this;

```
@DDL/table1.sql
@DDL/table2.sql
@fns/function1.sql
@fns/function2.sql
@views/view1.sql
```

Make sure each one commits where necessary and don't finish each individual script with EXIT.